# CompareValidator fails when both numbers are negative in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

I am populating two dropdownlists using an SQL datasource with the years of a number of events. I want to make sure that the second year is greater than or equal to the first. However, some of the dates are negative, indicating they are BCE. My CompareValidator works when the second year is positive but if both are negative it tells me that the second year is less than the first.

For example:

Year1: -2000

Year2: 123

This is fine and there is no problem with the comparison.

However if

Year1: -227

Year2: -13

It sometimes says Year2 is less than Year1.

Here is the code:

```
Start Date:  
<asp:DropDownList ID="Year1DropDown" runat="server"
DataSourceID="YearDataSource" DataValueField="YEAR" DataTextField="YEAR"
OnDataBound="AddDefaultItemYear1">
</asp:DropDownList><br />

End Date:
<asp:DropDownList ID="Year2DropDown" runat="server"
DataSourceID="YearDataSource" DataValueField="YEAR" DataTextField="YEAR"
OnDataBound="AddDefaultItemYear2">
</asp:DropDownList><br />

<asp:CompareValidator ID="CompareYears" runat="server" 
ControlToValidate="Year2DropDown" ControlToCompare="Year1DropDown"
Operator="GreaterThanEqual" ErrorMessage="End date must be greater than or equal to start date"></asp:CompareValidator>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must spesify the [Type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.basecomparevalidator.type%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) to `Integer`, because the default data type is `String`.

```
<asp:CompareValidator ID="CompareYears" runat="server" 
Type="Integer" 
ControlToValidate="Year2DropDown" ControlToCompare="Year1DropDown"
Operator="GreaterThanEqual" ErrorMessage="End date must be greater than or equal to start date"></asp:CompareValidator>
```

Comment: Thanks, I knew it had to be something stupid that I was simply missing and I see it was.